# Sass, check if file exists

Tags: sass

Is it possible to check if a file exists with sass (.scss)
I want to import a file if it exists and if not import another file. Is that possible?

I'm not using compass (suggested duplicate question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compass / Sass check if file exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601462/compass-sass-check-if-file-exists)

Comment: I'm not using compass

Comment: Oh, I just remembered seeing this question before, if not: false flag!
Does this mean `@import 'style.scss'` or `background-image: file.jpg`?

Comment: I don´t understand what you mean by that but what I want to do is to import a scss-file from another scss-file if it exists (with @import)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this.
If you import a file which doesn't exist, you will get an error immediately (even if it is placed under a false condition)

it is discussed [here](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/779)

also functionality of import described [here](https://jonathantneal.github.io/sass-import-resolve/) comprehensively